# How to make every possible transformation to a word in Java

Tags: java, transformation, cpu-word

I'm currently working on a program that will try and produce every possible transformation to a word based on the characters in the word. For example, if the word is hello then the program will print out all of the different variations such as hello, Hello, hellO, HellO, h3ll0, H3lL0, as so on until every combination is made. This is the program I have made so far:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Transformer{
    String input = null;

    public Transformer(){
        run();
    }

    public void run(){
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        System.out.println("Please enter a word:");

        try {
            input = br.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        //Convert String into char array
        char charArray[] = input.toCharArray();

        //Capitalise first letter
        if(Character.isLetter(charArray[0])){
            charArray[0] = Character.toUpperCase(charArray[0]);
        }
        System.out.println(charArray);

        //Reset transformation
        charArray = input.toCharArray();

        //Capitalise last letter
        if(Character.isLetter(charArray[charArray.length - 1])){
            charArray[charArray.length - 1] = Character.toUpperCase(charArray[charArray.length - 1]);
        }
        System.out.println(charArray);

        //Reset transformation
        charArray = input.toCharArray();


        //Iterate through charArray to make transformations to characters
        for(int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++){
            if(charArray[i] == 'a'){
                charArray[i] = '@';
                System.out.println(charArray);
            }

            if(charArray[i] == 'o'){
                charArray[i] = '0';
                System.out.println(charArray);
            }

            if(charArray[i] == 'e'){
                charArray[i] = '3';
                System.out.println(charArray);
            }

            if(charArray[i] == 's'){
                charArray[i] = '5';
                System.out.println(charArray);
            }

            if(charArray[i] == 'i'){
                charArray[i] = '1';
                System.out.println(charArray);
            }

            if(charArray[i] == 'l'){
                charArray[i] = '7';
                System.out.println(charArray);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, this only creates a limited number of transformations and adds them after each other instead of doing one transformation at a time, then two and so on. The only solution I can think of is a never ending list of if statements, but even then I'm not entirely sure how I could keep track of the changes. What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: You can make map of transformations for every char, and then use recursive method to transform all possible ways.

Comment: I understand how that would work for making transformations in sequence, like hello, Hello, h3llo, heLlo but would that also work for reiterating through and then making changes like H3llo, heLl0, H3ll0 and so on? And how would the function know when it's made every possible transformation so it can end instead of looping forever?

Comment: You have limited number of variants of transformations. So you loop will not be endless.

Comment: But you right, by the rules of combinatorics there is possible lots of transformations. Especially, in long words.

Comment: What would be the best way to structure the recursive function? And for the mapping of the characters, could I do something like this:
`Map<Object,ArrayList<Object>> charMap = new HashMap<Object,ArrayList<Object>>();
private ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
a.put('A');
a.put('@');
charMap.put('A', a);`
And then do this for every character?

Comment: Actually, your post looks as another question about homework. But in education purpose, I'll leave my solution below.

Comment: I did have an assignment recently that was similar but only wanted a few transformations made which I managed to complete using code similar to the block I posted above. The assignment gave me an idea of creating a program that can help people create more secure passwords by then looking at every transformation. Thanks for your responses though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I told you about something like this:

```
public class WordTransformer {

    private HashMap<Character, char[]> transformMap = new HashMap<Character, char[]>();
    {
        transformMap.put('h', new char[]{'H', 'h'});
        transformMap.put('e', new char[]{'3', 'E'});
        transformMap.put('l', new char[]{'I', 'L'});
        transformMap.put('o', new char[]{'0', 'O'});
    }

    public List<String> doTransform(String s){
        char[] stringChars = s.toCharArray();
        List<String> versions = new ArrayList<String>();
        doTransform(s, stringChars, 0, versions);
        return versions;
    }

    //This method is recursive
    private void doTransform(String s, char[] stringChars, int index,
        List<String> versions){

        //if we reached the end of string in current iteration
        //add generated variant into list
        if(index==s.length()){
            versions.add(new String(stringChars));
            return;
        }

        char c = s.charAt(index);
        if(transformMap.containsKey(c)){
            char[] transforms = transformMap.get(c);
            for(char t : transforms){
                stringChars[index] = t;
                //And this is recursive invocation, that means method calls itself
                doTransform(s, stringChars, index+1, versions);
            }
        }else {
            //if there is no such character in transform map, process next index
            doTransform(s, stringChars, index+1, versions);
        }
    }

}
```

Note, that private method `doTransform` calls for itself. This is called recursion method. Also note, that we pass into this method original String and array of `chars`. Array - is a place, where we build each version of original String. Usage:

```
WordTransformer transformer = new WordTransformer();
List<String> list = transformer.doTransform("hello");
for(String s : list){
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: This is great! Thanks!